# How to output that the server has been started

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following code, that it going to start a http server:

```
class MainVerticle : CoroutineVerticle() {

  override suspend fun start() {

    val server = vertx.createHttpServer()

    val router = Router.router(vertx)
    router.route("/api/genders*")
      .subRouter(GenderApi(vertx).create())

    server.requestHandler(router)
      .listen(8080)
      .await()

  }
}
```

Now, I would like to output, if the server has been successfully started or failed(in case the port has been already occupied).

Without the Coroutine, the codes would be:

```
class MainVerticle : AbstractVerticle() {

    override fun start(startPromise: Promise<Void>) {
        val server = vertx.createHttpServer()

        val router = Router.router(vertx)

        server.requestHandler(router).listen(8888) { http ->
            if (http.succeeded()) {
                startPromise.complete()
                println("HTTP server started on port 8888")
            } else {
                println(http.cause())
                startPromise.fail(http.cause());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I do output, if the server has been started success or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use coroutines, add a try/catch block:

```
class MainVerticle : CoroutineVerticle() {

  override suspend fun start() {

    val server = vertx.createHttpServer()

    val router = Router.router(vertx)
    router.route("/api/genders*")
      .subRouter(GenderApi(vertx).create())

    try {
      server.requestHandler(router)
        .listen(8080)
        .await()
      println("HTTP server started on port 8888")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      println(http.cause())
      throw e
    }

  }
}
```